# Limit $\lim_{n→∞} [log(2+3^n)]/2n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms

Find $\lim_{n→∞} [log(2+3^n)]/2n$

I have my work till the very last step then i dont know how to continue

$\lim_{n→∞} [log(2+3^n)]/2n$

=$\lim_{n→∞} log(3^n)+\lim_{n→∞} log[(2+3^n)/3n]$

=$\lim_{n→∞} log(3^n)+\lim_{n→∞} log[(2/3^n)+1/1]$

="I dont know what it is"$+1$

Since $\lim_{n→∞} log(3^n)$ is infinity???

What should I do?? Thanks!!

Comment: I dont know how it will work on this but another thing I tried to make it 
= $\lim_{n→∞} nlog(3)$
= $log(3)\lim_{n→∞} n$
still = ∞

Comment: How did you get your first step??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how your first step is valid.

But note
$$
{\log(3^n)\over 2n}\le {\log(2+3^n)\over 2n}\le  {\log( 3^{n+1})\over 2n}.
$$

Now use the Squeeze theorem (the power rule for logarithms will prove useful when computing the required limits of the left and right hand sides of the above inequality).

---

I think I see now what you were attempting:
$$
{\log(2+3^n)\over2n} 
={\log\bigl(3^n( {2\over3^n}+1)\bigr)\over2n} ={\log 3^n+\log  ( {2\over3^n}+1)
\bigr)\over2n}
=\color{maroon}{{\log 3^n\over 2^n}}+\color{darkgreen}{{\log  ( {2\over3^n}+1)\over 2n}}.
$$
This will prove useful:

$\displaystyle \qquad\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\color{darkgreen}{\log  ( {2\over3^n}+1)\over 2n}=0\ \ $ and  $\displaystyle\ \ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\color{maroon}{\log 3^n\over 2^n}={\log 3\over 2}$;$\ \ $ so
  $\displaystyle\ \ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\log(2+3^n)\over2n} ={\log 3\over 2}$.

Much cleaner than my solution!

Comment: I dont quite familiar with Squeeze theorem. Isn't it only useful when left and right limit are equal?

Comment: @Paul Compute $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\log(3^n)\over 2n }$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\log(3^{n+1})\over 2n }$. You'll see they are equal. This implies that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\log(2+3^n)\over 2n }$ exists and is equal to this common value.

Comment: So its $\lim_{n→∞} log(3n)/2n = \lim_{n→∞} nlog3 / 2n = \lim_{n→∞} log3 / 2 = log3 / 2$  ?

Comment: @Paul Yes, that's correct.

Comment: but i still dont know how you come up with this squeeze inequality... like how would i even think of that when doing the problems..

Comment: @Paul It's a theorem that's usually presented in an introductory calculus course (and a very useful one to know).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac { \log (2+3^n)}{\log {3^n} } = 1$

**Hint:** $\frac {\log 3^n}{2n} = \frac {n \log 3}{2n} = \frac {\log 3}{2}$. Hence the limit (of this sequence to infinity) is $\frac {\log 3}{2}$.

Answer (score -1):

Use LHopital's rule. lim log( 2 +3^n)/2n =  lim [ ln(2+3^n)/ln10]/2n
                                       = (1/ln10)lim[(1/(2+3^n))(3^n)ln3]/2
                                       = ln3/2ln10 lim[3^n/(2+3^n)
                                       = ln3/2ln10 lim [(3^n ln3)/(3^n ln3)]
                                       = (1/2)log3

Comment: Please use MathJax to format math-text (it is hard to read your answer). This link may be a useful reference for the formatting: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference